# “unmet dependencies” while installing gtk +3

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

Trying to install GTK as it was required by a another package.

So I ran 
`apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`

But getting unmet dependencies error.

Output

```
  Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.30.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.36.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I know that this error usually happents due to broken package.
But `apt-get install -f` show no problem.

Output of **`apt-get install -f`**

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Also no output for `apt-mark showhold`
Output for apt-cache of involde package
`sudo apt-cache policy  libgtk-3-dev`

```
 ibgtk-3-dev:
  Installed: (none)  
  Candidate: 3.16.7-0ubuntu3  
  Version table:  
     3.16.7-0ubuntu3 0  
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main i386 Packages
```

`apt-cache policy libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev`

```
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:  
  Installed: (none)  
  Candidate: 2.32.1-1  
  Version table:  
     2.32.1-1 0  
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main i386 Packages
```

`apt-cache policy libpango1.0-dev`

```
libpango1.0-dev:  
  Installed: (none)  
  Candidate: 1.36.8-3  
  Version table:  
     1.36.8-3 0  
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main i386 Packages
```

`apt-cache policy libcairo2-dev`

```
libcairo2-dev:  
  Installed: (none)  
  Candidate: 1.14.2-2ubuntu2  
  Version table:  
     1.14.2-2ubuntu2 0  
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main i386 Packages
```

`sudo apt-get check` and `sudo dpkg -C` has no output.
Output of `sudo apt-get update`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages                   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en                
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en                
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en                  
Reading package lists... Done
```

Output for `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main universe restricted multiverse
```

**EDIT:** I think  libpng12-0 is causing the problem tried to install libpng12-dev using apt-get  but got this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 libpng12-dev : Depends: libpng12-0 (= 1.2.51-0ubuntu3) but   1.2.51-0ubuntu3.15.10.2 is to be installed
```

Tried installing the latest version of libpng12-0 from source but still showing the same error.

**EDIT2(Sollution?):** Didn't do nothing much just installed libgtk-3-dev using aptitude and accepted the solution to downgrade libpng12-0 and it worked

Comment: Did try the solution givwn there it didnt work

Comment: Could you use the code formating instead of quotations? It makes harder to parse the information.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant @Braiam

Comment: Instead of using `>` just add four spaces around the lines of code. Read your question, what's the difference between the first grey blocks and the latter ones?

Comment: Can u tell me how to do that the first block was done by someone else.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: This is what you ment right? @Braiam

Comment: `sudo aptitude install libgtk-3-dev ` When prompted with "Accept this solution" you may need to enter "." to get to the next solution and then accept that solution (the second solution downgraded the repos that were giving me trouble"). Hope this helps someone.

Comment: your solution is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a case of *existing* broken dependencies (which `apt-get install -f` would attempt to fix), it's that **it can't get the packages it needs** to install the new package.

This could happen for a few reasons:

- You have an active repository that is suggesting a newer version of `libgtk-3-dev` (or its direct dependencies) which doesn't also include the right versions of the other dependencies.

  This can be a common issue for people who install tons of PPAs. Some versions get bumped so high that dependencies can't be worked out sufficiently.
- You don't have the right dependencies enabled (maybe something's in universe?)
- You haven't run an `apt-get update` recently?
- It's a straight-up bug in `libgtk-3-dev` (or one of its dependencies). File a report on Launchpad.

If you're just compiling stuff, a "quick" workaround for problems like this is to spin up a clean LXC (or other) virtual machine. This will let you start afresh without using up too much disk space.

Comment: I only had opera ppa extra. I trued deleting it and doing `apt-get update` but still same error